# Ayuda con codificacion Huffman Binary Tree JAVA con strings

Tags: java, árboles-binarios

```
public String codificar(String text) {
    String res="";
    if (!text.isEmpty()){
        for (int i = 0; i<text.length(); i++){
            res+=busquedaDelCaracter(text.charAt(i), this.huffmanTree, this.huffmanTree.root(), res);
        }
    }
    return res;
}


public String busquedaDelCaracter(Character ch, BinaryTree<Character> tree, Position<Character> pos, String path) {
    if(tree.isExternal(pos)){
        return path+busquedaDelCaracter(ch,tree,pos,path)==null?"":busquedaDelCaracter(ch,tree,pos,path);
    }
    if(tree.hasLeft(pos)){
        busquedaDelCaracter(ch,tree,tree.left(pos),"0"+path);
    }
    return path+busquedaDelCaracter(ch,tree,pos,path) == null?"":busquedaDelCaracter(ch,tree,tree.right(pos),"1"+path);     
}
```

Os pongo en situación:

Se trata de un ejercicio basado en la codificación Huffman, solamente trabajo con estructuras de datos sencillas.

Ejemplo de codificación Huffman:

```
            .
           / \
           a  .
               \
                .
               / \
              c  d

codificar("acd") ---> "0110111"
A la derecha = 1
A la izquierda = 0
```

---

Actualmente tengo el código que os he mostrado de codificar y el método recursivo `busquedaDelCaracter`. No sé dónde puede estar el fallo, ¿me podríais guiar un poco?

Nota, si no encuentra un carácter, es `null` pero al devolverlo no se pueden concatenar nulls.

Código ya realizado y con 0 problemas:

```
public String decode(String textocifrado) {

    Position <Character> cursor = this.huffmanTree.root();
    String decodeText="";

    for(int i=0; i<textocifrado.length(); i++){
        if(textocifrado.charAt(i) == '1'){
            cursor = this.huffmanTree.right(cursor);
        }
        if(textocifrado.charAt(i) == '0'){
            cursor = this.huffmanTree.left(cursor);
        }
        if(this.huffmanTree.isExternal(cursor)){
            decodeText+=cursor.element();
            cursor=this.huffmanTree.root();
        }           
    }   
    return decodeText;
}
```

Y el constructor sólo trabaja con un `char[]paths` con un `LinkedBinaryTree` llamado HuffmanTree y lo que hace es formar el árbol (no se necesita llamar al constructor) en el ejercicio que estoy pidiendo ayuda.

Comment: Después de leer dos veces la pregunta me he quedado igual. Supongo que piensas que esta clarísimo pero yo no sé exactamente en qué quieres que te ayudemos.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo: ¿lo que quieres es que alguien resuelva el ejercicio entero? Este no es lugar para eso, es mejor que lo intentes tu mismo y si tienes alguna DUDA CONCRETA, entonces pregunta sin miedo, pero no puedes pedir que hagamos tu ejercicio completo.

Comment: El ejercicicio entero no.Ya tengo hecho correctamente 2/3 parte de el, solo me falta el metodo de Codificar. El metodo de codificar esta correcto creo yo, y lo que me falla es el metodo recursivo al que llama, que es el "busquedaDelCaracter". El metodo recursivo lo que debe hacer es buscar el caracter en el arbol y devolver su path como el ejemplo que he puesto en el enunciado. El unico metodo que me falla es ese, he puesto el codigo de lo que llevo, pero no es correcto porque al probarlo no me hace lo que quiero que me haga.

Comment: ¿Cómo es que obtienes ese árbol? Mira, por ejemplo, [este](http://i.imgur.com/MKpaBBo.png)? ¿Qué *frecuencias* estás utilizando?